# EventEmiitter is not working in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

Hello I am new in angular 4 
I am trying implementing event emitter concept but it is not working.

I have following code in my demo

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    changeYearEvent($event: any) {
        console.log("called emit");
        console.log($event);
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div (yearHandler)="changeYearEvent($event);" class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <nav-menu></nav-menu>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-9 body-content'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**fetchdata.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'fetchdata',
    templateUrl: './fetchdata.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
    public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];
    @Output() yearHandler = new EventEmitter();
    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
            this.forecasts = result.json() as WeatherForecast[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }

    eventofClick() {
        console.log("emit call", "call");
        this.yearHandler.emit("hii");
    }
}

interface WeatherForecast {
    dateFormatted: string;
    temperatureC: number;
    temperatureF: number;
    summary: string;
}
```

**fetchdata.component.html**

```
<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

<p *ngIf="!forecasts"><em>Loading...</em></p>
<a (click)="eventofClick()">Hello</a>
<table class='table' *ngIf="forecasts">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>
            <th>Temp. (F)</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let forecast of forecasts">
            <td>{{ forecast.dateFormatted }}</td>
            <td>{{ forecast.temperatureC }}</td>
            <td>{{ forecast.temperatureF }}</td>
            <td>{{ forecast.summary }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I declared yearHandler as @output variable in fetchdata.component.ts 
then implemented  eventofClick() event , from that function i emmit event

yearHandler  declared in app.component.html that call changeYearEvent($event);

and when changeYearEvent is called it display message in console.log
but it is not calling changeYearEvent

Can anyone please help me what is wrong in this.

Thank You.

Comment: Please have a look at https://angular.io/tutorial to get basic understanding of angular works and how to use a component in another component

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `fetchdata` as selector instead of `div` as the `@Output` works for the component

```
<fetchdata (yearHandler)="changeYearEvent($event);">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <nav-menu></nav-menu>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-9 body-content'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</fetchdata>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event is emitted "from the component" so you need to attach the event listener on the component. Now its assigned on a seemingly random div (your outermost). You need to have your component in a template like this, with your event handler on it:

```
<div>
   <fetchdata (yearHandler)="changeYearEvent($event)"></fetchdata>
</div>
```

If you actually want to catch the event from "somewhere else" but the parent template. You need to have a common service that both components inject in the constructor, that share an Subject/Observable, that the recievers can subscribe to, and your calendar can emit on.